# how to include ZXing in iphone project

Tags: iphone, zxing

I have downloaded ZXing 1.5 and am trying to include this in my iPhone project.

I have got the Barcode iphone project provided by Zxing to build on its own (And i can offer advice n this if any one is stuck)

But i am unsure how i would now incorporate this project into mine?

Which classes are needed?

What linking paths are needed?

If anyone has done this you advice would be highly appreciated.

Or if someone could just point me in the right direction that would be very helpful also

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the source, it has an iPhone example called **ScanTest** which includes the ZXingWidget just like you would in your own project. The readme inside there also goes over linkages etc. and what to do if you get certain errors.

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/00f634024ceeee591f54e6984ea7dd666fab22ae/iphone